# Geocoding for full addresses

Tags: sas

I have more than two million records in my dataset. The addresses are in full, not parsed out into fields such as address number, street, city and state. There isn't a standardized pattern in the way these addresses are formed and since there are two million records, I can't investigate the whole dataset fully.

Neither can I change anything in the address field as I pulled the dataset from my company's database.

I want to turn addresses into longitudes and latitudes, but the procedure from SAS requires addresses being parsed into smaller fields and as I mentioned above, it's not practical for me to do so.

http://support.sas.com/documentation/cdl/en/graphref/63022/HTML/default/viewer.htm#overview-geocode.htm

My company is in Financial sector, so due to security measures, I can't install 3rd party software or applications. I need to do so in SAS Enterprise. If you have any suggestion, that'd be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Could you please explain what is your exact requirement?

Comment: So what have you coded ? What is impractical about parsing ? Are the addresses international ? This is the first time the company has tried geocoding in its operations or campaigns ?

Comment: 1. Find a method of parsing that works for a decent chunk of your unparsed data. 2. Go to step 1 and repeat until everything is parsed or you reach the point of diminishing returns, whichever is first.